# How to avoid an unsaved entity while fetching data in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

This is my first project where I am using Core Data with sqlite as the backing store. 
Here are the quick details of the scenario:

- There is a feedback form that gets filled in one screen.
- There is a screen where I can see saved forms.
- The form data can be synced with back-end server.
- I am using MKNetworkingKit for interacting with REST API. (Looks like I should have looked at RestKit, but I dont have time to go back)
- When I save the form I save the data in the main managedObjectContext of the application to the persistentStore.
- In the form screen I have a sync button that syncs the application data with backend.
- Also while saving the data locally, I check for connectivity and push the rest of the unsynced data to the server.
- In the screen where I have saved forms, there also I have a sync button to sync data.

My Problem is that in the screen while I am filling a form and the form info in entity is not complete, and its in an inconsistent state.

I use the same method of my dataManager singleton to do the syncing.
In other screens where I sync data, my managed object context is in consistent state and I can sync the data, but while filling the form I want to avoid the entity I am working on and have not saved it.

What should I be doing now to get things done quickly?

Also what should be the ideal way of designing such application using core data?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the actual entity until the form data is complete and validated.  If you need an intermediate place to store it while editing is happening, invent an object with the same data fields but which isn't a managed object.  (Java people used to do this regularly with the Data Transfer Object pattern.)